# How to find the radical of this Lie algebra

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

Let $k$ be a field, and for $1 < m < n, \ $  let $\ \mathfrak{g}_m = \{ (a_{ij})_{ij} \in \mathfrak{gl}(n,k): a_{ij} = 0 \text{ for } i > m\}.$ What is the radical of $ \mathfrak{g}_m$? I tried working it out for small values of $n$ and $m$, but otherwise I'm stuck.

Comment: If you write that down, that's the matrices such that all rows after row number $m$ are $0$. Then I would split that into $m\times m$ matrices in the top left corner, and the $m\times (n-m)$ "overhang" on the top right. The top left block identifies with $\mathfrak{gl}(m, k)$. The overhanging block is ... a solvable ideal maybe?

Comment: Yep, checks out, thanks!